# Suggestion/Help regarding text mining

Tags: lucene, text-mining

I need to do text mining on a single document using Map-Reduce concept.

A few of my friends suggested me to use Apache Lucene.

But after going thorugh few documents about Apache Lucene, I found that it can be useful only when we need to index documents.

Can anyone suggest me on any better methods ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Apache Mahout is a data mining library for Hadoop

Answer (score 0):

Lucene is a framework for document indexing and retrieval. Of course one could play around with indexed data like keyword search, document similarity etc.

If you are interested in TM, have a look on OpenNLP and LingPipe. They have 100s of libraries for text mining and natural language processing.